# Expected distance between $k$ points on $n$ slots.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have $n$ ball slots numbered $1$ to $n$. In the first try, I throw $k$ balls with uniform probability that land in indices $f(1),f(2), ..., f(k)$. Then, I remove the balls, and throw them again uniformly and they land in $g(1), g(2), ..., g(k)$.

My question is, what is the expectation $$\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^k |f(i)-g(i)|)$$

For $k=1$, this is just the expected distance between two random points, which would be $\frac{n+1}{3}$, but for $k=2$, it gets a bit complicated with the relative ordering in each throw. Any help?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are the balls identifiable?  In other words, is $i$ the same ball for each pair $(f(i), g(i))$?  If not, then how are the $f(i)$ and $g(i)$ related?  Specifically, how do you uniquely determine the values $f(1), f(2), \ldots$?  For example, if $n = 5$ and $k = 3$, and the balls land in slots $3, 1, 4$ in some unspecified order, which one of these is $f(1)$?

Comment: @heropup $f(1)$ represents their order in increasing order, I missed that. For example, in your example, f(1)=1, f(2)=3, f(3)=4

Comment: So for example, if n=5, k=3, and in the first throw, the balls fall in $3,1,4$ and in the second throw, they fall in $3,2,5$, then $f(1)=1, f(2)=3, f(3)=4$ and $g(1)=2, g(2)=3, g(3)=5$